# How can i wrap SliverGrid.Count inside the Container or any widget to provide background Color to slivergrid.count.and after continuous scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

ScrollController scrollController;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Scaffold(
body:SafeArea(
child:Stack(
children:[

```
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Image.asset("assets/p11.jpg",fit: BoxFit.fill,),
        ),
         CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
               backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              pinned: false,
              floating: false,
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(20),topLeft:Radius.circular(20))
                ),
                child: Text("Jay Swaminarayan",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),
            ),

                  SliverGrid.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 0,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.3,
                      children:List<Widget>.generate(
                          20,(index){
                          return Container(
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                              child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              color: Colors.orange,
```

- 

---

),
);
}
)
),
],
),
],
),
)
);
}